# How to create layout for "small" devices with sw qualifier?

Tags: android, android-layout

As I understand `layout-small`, `layout-normal`, `layout-large` are deprecated and the recommended way of creating layout for a devices' set is to use sw. For example `layout-sw320` is for devices which have one of it's side with value >= 320dp. But "small" and "normal" devices have the same sw.

So the question is how properly distinguish "small" and "normal" devices with sw qualifier? Is it possible? Do I need to fall back to old style ?

Answer (score 0):

The new device dimension classifiers aim to support based on the smallest width of the device; not so much the height. If your application is relying on the height, you will have to support the orientations separately or disable them using the [`screenOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) property in the `AndroidManifest.xml` `<activity>` attribute.

For example, using `screenOrientation="sensorPortrait|portrait"` allows you to rely on the `swXXX` only, but if you support all screen orientations you can support them with:

- `layout-w320-port`, which is called for `small` *and* `large` screens in the old specification when in portrait
- EDIT: You could use `layout-w320-h426-port` and `layout-w320-h470-port` when you want to differentiate between the two in portrait mode specifically.
- `layout-w426-land` for the previous `small` screen, when in landscape orientation
- `layout-w470-land` for the previous `large` screen, when in landscape orientation

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after some extra research I've understood that the idea to find boundaries for "small" devices with new qualifiers was wrong, so we need to refactor old layouts to meet new concept.

Answer (score 0):

in manifest -

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

check the link - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html and 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html